# List orders from Woocmmerce using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, woocommerce

I am new to web application development. I need to list new orders from Woocommerce to a simple web app.
I am getting JSON response for all orders from my woocommerce shop when i tried to make GET Request through POSTMAN(through Woocommerce REST API). Actually I need to show new orders on the web app and a print button next to each order, that's all.
My question is, can I develop this simple web app using SpringBoot which talks with Woocommerce REST API or with any other JS frameworks, if so, how to implement this. Your simple suggestions will be great for my learning.

Thank you

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/ maybe this tutorial will help you? It shows you how you can make REST API calls from your spring boot project

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will look in to it.

Comment: Is there any way to display print button next to each order, that need to print a simple template....